# I want to delete multiple CRM records from Dynamics with Xrm.WebApi.online.executeMultiple

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

Multiple entity records have to be deleted in one call instead of multiple callbacks so trying to use Xrm.WebApi.online.executeMultiple to delete records. but the code written below is not working. Any help will be appreciated.

```
            for (var i=0; i<Checkbox.length; i++)
            {
                if(Checkbox[i].checked)
                {
                    var id = Checkbox[i].value;// GUID of the record to be deleted
                    Checkbox[i].checked = false;

                    DeleteRequests[i]={};
                    DeleteRequests[i].getMetadata = function(){
                        return{
                            boundParameter: undefined,
                            operationType: 2,
                            operationName: "Delete",
                            parameterTypes: {
                            }
                        }

                    }
                    DeleteRequests[i].etn="cme_entity";
                    DeleteRequests[i].payload=id;
                }
            }
            window.parent.Xrm.WebApi.online.executeMultiple(DeleteRequests).then(
                function (results) {alert("Success");},
                function (error) {alert("Failed");});
```

Getting weird error that this operation could not be processed. Please contact Microsoft.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue has to do with how you are constructing the delete request objects. You need to declare a function that sets up the `getMetadata` function and the required `entityReference` object.

I've tested the below solution and it works.

```
var Sdk = window.Sdk || {};

Sdk.DeleteRequest = function (entityReference) {
    this.entityReference = entityReference;
    this.getMetadata = function () {
        return {
            boundParameter: null,
            parameterTypes: {},
            operationType: 2,
            operationName: "Delete",
        };
    };
};

for (var i = 0; i < Checkbox.length; i++) {
    if (Checkbox[i].checked) {
        var id = Checkbox[i].value;
        Checkbox[i].checked = false;

        DeleteRequests[i] = new Sdk.DeleteRequest({ entityType: "account", id: id }); 
    }
}

window.parent.Xrm.WebApi.online.executeMultiple(DeleteRequests).then(
    function (results) { alert("Success"); },
    function (error) { alert("Failed"); });
```

Unfortunately CRUD operations with `Xrm.WebApi.online.execute` and `Xrm.WebApi.online.executeMultiple` are not very well documented. I've written a  [blog post with some code samples](https://ryanjames.dev/blog/2019/09/16/crud-operations-with-xrm-webapi-online-execute-and-executemultiple#execute-multiple-delete).

The important parts are the declaration of the `Sdk.DeleteRequest` function as a property on `window` and instantiating a request object using `new Sdk.DeleteRequest()`. I experimented a little and determined that just simply creating a request object like you were doing before, even with the right attributes does not work either.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Hi Ryan,
Thanks for your response, but I am still below error.
An error has occurred. Try this action again. If the problem continues, check the Microsoft Dynamics 365 Community for solutions or contact your organization's Microsoft Dynamics 365 Administrator. Finally, you can contact Microsoft Support.

Comment: @ApurvYadav Sorry for the incorrect answer earlier. I was running into the same errors as you were when I actually tested it. So I've updated my answer with a working solution that I've tested :)